# dynatree knockout binding issue

Tags: knockout.js, dynatree

I'm using dynatree together with knockout. The view model contains a 'isManager' boolean property I want to have displayed using a checkbox.

The problem is that after the dynatree binding is applied I appear to have lost the binding to the isManager property.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/markachten/UhA3m/

Now I'm not sure if this is a knockout issue or a dynatree issue. Could it be in the definition of the binding handler? I have to put in some code here when referencing jsFiddle and I'm not sure if pasting the entire code is handy... Anyway, is it in the definition of the binding?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dynatree = {
    ...        
};
```

Or do I need to pass in some extra binding options?

```
{
    noLink: true,
    minExpandLevel: 2
    // what should go here?
}
```

Some additional comments regarding the code:
I was forced to set the 'noLink' property to true in the dynatree. If set to false, I can not check the checkboxes. And I'm using a span within a span to display both the name and the input element.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to execute your custom binding **dynatree** after the template html is fully rendered right ??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is `dynatree` issue(i have the same with [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)).

The problem here is that to `dynatree` plugin  to be able to draw the tree it need to add new elements to your html. In other words it **Restructure** your html again.

You can check this by checking the result html in inspector. You 'll find that your `data-bind` is no longer exist !!!.

So to solve this issue you need to put your custom binding `dynatree` on your `<ul>`

```
<div id="dynatree" data-bind="">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: persons },dynatree: {}"></ul>
</div>
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/UhA3m/5/)**

Comment: Thanks, but moving the binding to the <ul> does not turn the <ul> into a treeview. And that is why I'm using dynatree in the first place...